# Different elements position in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

I faced with the problem that I have different AppBar icon paddings in my Flutter app.
I tried to solve it with package providing a responsive measuring (something like dp) instead of pixels, even though there is no padding in Pixel's (second phone) app bar icon I have to place text a lot more lower than it should be on Nexus phone

[image: Difference Nexus 6/Pixel 5]

Here is my code:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final backgroundColor = 0xffF6F6F6;
  final accentColor = 0xff8c84e2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(360, 690),
      builder:() => MaterialApp(
        // theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor: Color(backgroundColor),
                expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                leading: Builder(
                  builder: (context) => IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    tooltip: 'открыть меню',
                    icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                    onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
                  ),
                ),
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    background: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 500.w,
                      height: 500.h,
                      child: CustomPaint(
                        painter: CirclePainter(),
                      ),
                    ),

                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.h, left: 17.h),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text('Подборки',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 24,
                                fontFamily: 'Consolas')),
                      ),
                    ),

                    Positioned(
                      top: 110,
                      right: 10,
                      child: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          'Открыть всё',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontFamily: 'Consolas'),
                        ),
                        style: ButtonStyle(),
                      ),
                    ),
```

How can I make it identical on both phones?

Comment: A good way to start solving the problem yourself, or to help ask a better question, is to start reducing the code you posted, and see what's the "minimal" code required to reproduce the issue. This way the problem can be isolated and maybe you will figure it out, or at least, make the question easier to read for others.

Comment: @user1032613 the problem is not about code directly, it's more about flutter at all, there is not a question or errors in the code, so I've shared it to fully understand the context and let people help me with some examples of good code and show what I can make better.
The problem is mostly shown in pictures and it's quite common problem for flutter developers, so there could be no code at all to understand the problem I've faced, if there is concrete way I can do to help you to answer the question it will be great.